# Having issues getting the setTitle function to work with nextButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

After running the code, everything works except for the `setTitle` command that would change the text inside the button. I've tried everything and even copied tutorials, but no luck. I started Swift 2 days ago so any help would be great!

```
CVAimport UIKit

class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    var slides: [OnboardingSlide] = []
    
    var currentPage = 0 {
        didSet {
            if currentPage == slides.count - 1 {
                nextButton.setTitle("GET STARTED", for: .normal)
            } else {
                nextButton.setTitle("NEXT", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        slides = [
            OnboardingSlide(title: "", description: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "", description: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "")),
            OnboardingSlide(title: "", description: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "")),
        ]
        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            currentPage += 1
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
    
}

extension OnboardingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return slides.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OnboardingCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(slides[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let width = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / width)
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
    }
}
```

I tried pretty much everything I could think of, but I'm new to Swift and can't figure out why the title change is working for my labels and text but not the text in the button.

Comment: What is actually happening with the your `nextButton` title? Please clarify in what way it is not behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: I'm attempting to make the text in the button change from "next" to "get started" when the onboarding screen is on the last slide. However, I think my issue has to do with the setTitle command, as the text in the button doesn't update regardless of which slide it's on (I tried to set the title to all caps with the line nextButton.setTitle("NEXT", for: .normal), and the text stayed lower case, so I assume its not registering at all for some reason. Appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "new" style buttons (the default when adding them in Storyboard), you need to use the [UIButton.Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration) features.

Quick example (without the distraction code):

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    
    var currentPage = 0 {
        didSet {
            var cfg = nextButton.configuration
            if currentPage == 3 {
                //nextButton.setTitle("GET STARTED", for: .normal)
                cfg?.title = "GET STARTED"
            } else {
                //nextButton.setTitle("NEXT", for: .normal)
                cfg?.title = "NEXT"
            }
            nextButton.configuration = cfg
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        currentPage += 1
        print("current Page:", currentPage)
    }
    
}
```